# Symfony 5 - Unable to load fixtures with phpunit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, fixtures

I am trying to load my fixtures (php file) from phpunit.

I installed LiipTestFixture, and in my AbstractControllerTest.php :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use App\Entity\App\User;
use App\Services\App\EntrepriseServiceTest;
use Liip\TestFixturesBundle\Test\FixturesTrait;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

abstract class AbstractControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    use FixturesTrait;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        if (!$this->client) {
            $this->client = static::createClient();
        }

        $this->loadFixtures([
                "App\DataFixtures\AppFixtures",
            ])->getReferenceRepository();
    }
```

My fixtures class :

```php
class AppFixtures extends Fixture implements FixtureInterface
{
//...
}
```

But when I launch my tests, I've no error, but the fixtures don't charge.
Can someone help me please ?

PS: I'm using MySql database

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySql database

Comment: Have you set up a separate database for the test environment? How do you see that the fixtures were not loaded? Is the database empty after running the tests?

Comment: Yes I've a specific database for test environment. Ans yes, the database is still empty after test execution. But no errors displayed

Comment: Show us your AppFixtures class. Did you call `persist` and `flush`? Like here https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#writing-fixtures

Comment: Yes I did call these methods. The problem is probably different because if I run the command  `php bin/console d:f:l` in the terminal, everything works fine. https://pastebin.com/KFxqdT7j

Comment: I see `flush` method, but I don't see `persist` called before. Is it defined somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, the persist method is called in the others functions

Comment: Okay it works now ! I just did a cache:clear, and now it works... weird... but thank you all !